# Python implementation of Nearest Neighbour (Graph Theory) not working due to multidimensional arrays passed by reference not value

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I've attempted to build the nearest neighbour algorithm where by a route across all nodes is found by picking the node with the least weight to travel there, and then repeating until all nodes are traversed. I've tested it and the code appears not to be working due to the arrays being passed by reference, and not by value. This is despite the use of [:]

Where have I gone wrong? Any help would be much appricated

```
def nearest_neighbour(matrix):
    shortest = sum(row[0] for row in matrix[:])+1
    best_route = None

    for row_index in range(len(matrix[:])):
        test_time = 0
        route = [row_index]
        temp_matrix = matrix[:]
        index = row_index
        for i in temp_matrix:

            for row in temp_matrix:
                row[index] = sum(row)

            current_row = temp_matrix[row_index]
            score = min(current_row)
            index = current_row.index(score)
            test_time += score
            route.append(index)
        if shortest > test_time:
                    shortest = test_time
                    best_route = route
    return shortest, best_route[:-1]



a = [
    [0, 3610, 2959, 3536],
    [3861, 0, 1828, 243],
    [3129, 1706, 0, 1632],
    [3731, 242, 1698, 0]
    ]

nearest_neighbour(a[:])
```

edit: I have added an if statement at the end of the function where there was none initially

Comment: Reevaluate your use of the [:] operator, I don't think it does what you are intending to do. Also I don't understand what you are doing, I'm not sure the premise behind your code makes sense...

Comment: 1) Those are *list objects*, not arrays. 2) Nothing is ever passed by reference in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Using a slice like `matrix[:]` only makes a shallow copy of a list of lists. That is, you've copied the outer list, but the new list contains references to the same inner lists the original list did. You probably need to copy the inner lists too if you're going to be rewriting their values and don't want that to see the effects in the original list of lists.

It's probably a good idea to use `copy.deepcopy` to copy a nested data structure. That said, your current code makes a whole bunch of copies that are probably unnecessary. You don't need to copy something if you're just going to call `len` on it or iterate over it without adding or removing elements.

I'm also rather suspicious of your `for i in temp_matrix[:]` loop, since you never use `i` in the loop body. I don't actually understand what you're trying to compute though, so I don't have a specific fix to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the premise of your code makes sense for a multi-dimensional nearest neighbor algorithm. While it will return the correct solution, you will be doing far more comparisons than the brute force solution which is already inefficient.

Here is a brute-force implementation of NN in numpy:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np


def nearest_neighbour(a,b,axis=1):
    """
    Finds the index of nearest point in `b` for each point in `a` if axis=1,
    otherwise vice-versa for axis=0.
    """

    ex_a, k = a.shape
    ex_b, k = b.shape

    distance_squared = np.sum(np.square(a.reshape(ex_a,1,k) -\
        b.reshape(1,ex_b,k)),axis=-1)

    # find the nearest point in `b` to each point in `a`
    # *or*
    # find the nearest point in `a` to each point in `b`
    ia = np.argmin(distance_squared,axis=axis)

    return ia


a = np.random.randn(5,5)
b = np.random.randn(15,5)
print nearest_neighbour(a,b)
```

This code is a fairly (runtime) efficient (*but not memory efficient*!) implementation of ***brute force*** NN in numpy using [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html). However, this is *still* brute force and scales poorly with the the number of dimensions. If you want efficiency at the cost of correctness to solve the multi-dim NN problem, please consider employing the research efforts already done on this problem, in particular check out [FALCONN](https://falconn-lib.org/) which gives a reasonable accuracy vs runtime trade off. If you try to recreate this yourself, be prepared to spend weeks on implementing and understanding the ideas behind speeding up multi-dim NN!